# Simple try-catch block but complicated requirement

Tags: java, exception, for-loop, try-catch

This is a very basic question  and I was wondering how can I do that.
Consider a sample code below.This is not a Original code.There is complex code where I wish to implement a similar concept

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
    try {
        accountoutlist = accountstub.accountUpdate(accountinlist);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error Occurred: " + e);
    }
}
```

I want whenever the Exception happens, the program should continue with the for loop.
The output Should be.
To phrase it" If the exception occurs then ignore it and continue with for loop"

This is what output should be like, supposing if an exception occured after 6.Wish Java had GOTO statment like BASIC language

```
0
1
2
3
Error Occured
4
```

If the 1st part is very easy, next I would Like this(exception to be ignored)  only when an exception error(e) says

```
Error Occured: Update operation on integration component 'Account' failed because no
matching record in business component 'Account' with search
specification '[Id] = "ALEA-2KXVN0"' could be found.(SBL-EAI-04403)
```

Comment: One thing you can do is to throw a specific error code from the accountUpdate call.  This can be handled appropriately.

Comment: This is webservice not hosted by Me. i just Consume it. This is the error when i print it(e). how can i make the program to ignore only this kind of error

Answer (score 0):

Java has `goto` as a reserved word but it is not used.

So you cannot do it with `goto`.
I assume you have more statements after the catch block.

So you can do this:

Declare a boolean flag `error` before the loop.

Set it to `false` as first line in your loop.
Set it to `true` in the catch block.

After the try-catch block (at whatever line you need it) do this: `if (error) continue;`

Comment: He doesn't need that though. The loop will automatically continue since he caught the exception.

Comment: @TimB I assume he has more statements after the catch block.

Comment: @TimB "I want whenever the Exception happens, the program should continue with the for loop" So I think that's exactly what OP needs.

Comment: TBH he's only posted half the code and the question is very vague so I think we've done as much as we can.

Comment: You can just do the continue directly from the catch block in any case.

Comment: @TimB Good point. Updated answer: "After the try-catch block (at whatever line you need it) do this: if (error) continue;"

Comment: I agree with Tim B. All I want is it should go back to the For Loop. I  want the code after FOR loop to be executed only after FOR loop has finished and I dont the program to get interrupted when an exception comes.

Answer (score 0):

If the exception doesn't match (for example using the string `beginsWith()` method to check) then throw the exception again inside your catch. If your try-catch is inside the loop then unless you throw the exception again the loop will continue automatically.

You would be better off catching only the specific exception type you want (i.e. `NoMatchingRecordException` rather than catching all `Exception`s though.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);

        try {
            accountoutlist = accountstub.accountUpdate(accountinlist);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Ignore
            System.out.println("Error Occurred: " + e);
            // Skip perfroming further operations. Continue to the next record
            continue;
        }

        // Further operations on the data.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify catched exception message and **rethrow** if error is important for you

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
    try {
        accountoutlist = accountstub.accountUpdate(accountinlist);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (e.getMessage().equals("Error Occured: Updat....")) {
            throw e;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error Occurred: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

But in general better is to usage exception hierarchy and separate fatal errors from ignorable errors.

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty of modifying your code just a bit in order to make it easier to understand by Java rookies.

So, you should put a label before the for statement and then inside the catch block put a continue statement to that respective label:

```
int i;
ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
returnPoint:for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
    String buggedPoint = null;
    try {
        if(i == 3) {
            buggedPoint = "bugged";
            arrayList.add(Integer.valueOf(buggedPoint));
    }
    arrayList.add(i);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error Occurred: " + e);
        continue returnPoint;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
Error Occurred: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "bugged"
4
```

See also the ContinueWithLabelDemo from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html